# PHP remove number from comma seperated string stored in db

Tags: php, string, str-replace, replace

I am storing numbers in a database with a string like `5,55,15,17,2,35`

I want to remove say number 5 from the string, keeping the comma seperation set like it is.

The problem with using `str_replace()` is that all of the 5's will be removed. If i use `str_replace('5,'', $string)` thats fine, but the comma wouldn't be after the 5 if it was in the middle of the string or at the end. That same str_replace would also remove part of 15, and 55,

Am i missing something?

Comment: Storing numbers like that is quite horrible practice for exactly this reason among a whole host of others.

Comment: @Ratbum: Comma-delimited lists may not be the most ideal number storage format, but there are cases when you have unknown (but small) quantities of simple integers; to add a separate table might be more complex than simply parsing the single-column list.

Comment: @JYelton I had to work with something that was set up like this recently (although a bit worse). It only made things more awkward. It seems to be doing the same here.

Comment: It seems to be working fine, although yeah it feels a little hackish. Am looking at changing the model

Comment: The site is built purely using jquery/ajax calls to PHP/MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = explode(',', $string);
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
  if ($v == 5) unset($array[$k]);
$string = implode(',', $array);
```

You probably shouldn't be storing a comma separated list of values in a single database column in the first place. It looks like a one-to-many association, which should be modeled with a separate table.

Comment: The database contains projects that have milestones and tasks. Each project has a "milestone_order" column that has the comma seperated list, and each milestone has a "task_order" column that has the comma seperated list of tasks that belong to that milestone.

Comment: Right, that's not how you model that. You create a `project_milestone_order` TABLE and a `milestone_task_order` TABLE, with columns `(project_id, milestone_id, order)` and `(milestone_id, task_id, order)`. Each association is a row. To delete all the 5s, you `DELETE FROM project_milestone_order WHERE order = 5`. If you're ever storing multiple values in a single column, you have a denormalized table and should reconsider your schema.

Comment: That model sounds confusing, as when i update the order i have to change every single row for every milestone/task

Comment: That's poor database design. There should be a project_milestones table with columns project_id, milestone_id, order, and a milestone_tasks table with columns milestone_id, task_id, order.

Comment: That makes sense, but what kind of query would you run to change the order?

Comment: Multiple `UPDATE` queries. In your app, when someone reorders the items, you compare the old order to the new order and issue an `UPDATE` query for each item whose order changed.

@Barmar I made that exact comment 8 minutes ago...

Comment: Interesting. Am going to play around with that.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string first by comma so you can work with the numbers directly. Remove 5 from the array, then recombine the array into a comma-delimited string.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
    $input = '5,55,15,17,2,35';
    echo "Input: $input<br />";

    // Split the string by "exploding" the string on the delimiter character
    $nums = explode(',', $input);

    // Remove items by comparing to an array containing unwanted elements
    $nums = array_diff($nums, array(5));

    // Combine the array back into a comma-delimited string
    $output = implode(',', $nums);

    echo "Output: $output<br />";

    // Outputs:
    // Input: 5,55,15,17,2,35
    // Output: 55,15,17,2,35

?>
```

Comment: I would assume they downvoted before you put an example up. Anyhow, all these work perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I thought downvotes were for non-useful answers, not example-less answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace([$num.",",",".$num],"",$input);
```

Comment: explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

U can try something like this:

```
// Convert string into array of numbers
$arrOfNumbers = explode(',', $string);

// Find id of number for del
$numberForDelId = array_search($numberForDel, $arrOfNumbers);

//Delete number
unset($arrOfNumbers[$numberForDelId]);

// Convert back to string
$resultString = implode(',' $arrOfNumbers)
```

Comment: Whoops, looks like I didn't go far enough in the time machine when duplicate hunting.  Your technique is already there.

Answer (score -1):

You should:

1. get the string
2. then "explode" the values into an array
3. and re-create the string without the number you want to remove.